# Alguien me puede explicar este LINQ de C# (mas que todo el signo "!" y el contains) y convertirlo a una Query de SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
            q = (from c in db.CopiasDelLibro
                 where c.LibroId == idLib &&
                 !(from a in db.AlquileresDelLibro where a.FechaRealDevolucion.Year == 1900 select a.CopiaDelLibroId).Contains(c.Id)
                 select c).ToList();
```

Comment: Hace un especie de JOIN con AlquileresDelLibro para excluir los libros que se hayan devuelto en el año 1900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es la siguiente selección:

> ***A)*** Selecciona todos los elementos de `CopiasDelLibro` (cada uno se llamará `c`) donde de cada elemento (`c`) su `LibroId` sea igual al *idLib*.

> ***B)*** Selecciona la propiedad `CopiaDelLibroId` de todos los elementos de `AlquileresDelLibro` (cada uno se llamará `a`) donde de cada elemento (`a`) su `FechaRealDevolucion.Year` sea 1990.

> ***C)*** De la lista que resulte **A**, selecciona los elementos `c` que, además de la primera condición, **en la lista B *no* se encuentre el `Id`** (`!Contains`) de ese elemento `c`.

Transformado a SQL, sería más o menos así:

```sql
SELECT C.*
  FROM CopiasDelLibro C
 WHERE C.LibroId = @idLib AND C.Id NOT IN (SELECT A.CopiaDelLibroId
                                             FROM AlquileresDelLibro A
                                            WHERE YEAR(A.FechaRealDevolucion) = 1990)
```

Comment: Excelente brow, gracias por la respuesta muy util

Answer (score 0):

En Linq, el símbolo de exclamación hace referencia el metodo "exclude".
Lo que hace tu query es obtener una lista cuya propiedad LibroId sea igual a tu varibala idLib y excluye a aquellos cuya fecha de devolucación sea igual a 1900.

Comment: ***En Linq*** no, en C#. El operador `!` significa negación en cualquier contexto donde se evalue una expresión de tipo `bool`, que es lo que ocurre en el `where`, no es una _referencia_ a algún método `Exclude`.